# problem when creating bootable usb in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, server, xubuntu, lts

i am using ubuntu LTS and i want to create a bootable usb. so I opened the Startup disc creator in ubuntu, the problem is despite I selectIchoose the desired .iso file, it is never listed and hence i cant create the bootable usb.

anz suggestions_

Comment: What do you mean by "It is never listed" ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm, usually, use `dd if=/path/to/iso of=/path/to/usb && sync` for creating bootable usb disk. Or, as alternative solution [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

well, you can try https://unetbootin.github.io/  or http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
you need to try different tools and command because one method sometimes are not suitable for everyone

Comment: i am on ubuntu but i want to create a bootable usb for windows

Answer (score 0):

Try other tools instead of the build in Startup disk creator. On linux I have used UnetBootin multiple times, otherwise you can always grab a DVD and burn the .iso on it using K3B. (Awesome burning software BTW)

*edit* Last week I wanted to go from elementary OS to Windows 10 and I tried to create a bootable USB but it kept failing on me, so I deceided to burn a DVD as I said using k3b and it worked like a charm. :)